# How can I debug the "not found" message in my JS code?

Tags: javascript

I got the following code which is a search bar using binary search to search for the products according to their ids. when I enter the non exist product instead of print out the alert not found, it keeps show up the error in console which is can't read the property length of undefined.

### Edit

I just insert the html and the error is in the line 8 of the js.

```js
info = [{id:0, title:"notebook", price:12.24}, {id:1, title:"pencil", price:2.75},
        {id:2, title:"Ruler", price:12.24}, {id:3, title:"eraser", price:12.24},
        {id:4, title:"Crayon", price:2.75}, {id:5, title:"brush", price:12.24},
        {id:6, title:"pen", price:2.75}, {id:7, title:"Sketchbook", price:12.24},
        {id:8, title:"Case", price:2.75}, {id:9, title:"Mechanical pencil", price:12.24}]

function Searching(key, info) {
    var n = info.length;
    if (n == 0) return false;
    if (n == 1) {
        if(key == info[0]["id"]) return true;
        return false;
    }
    var mid = Math.floor(n/2) - 1;
    if (key == info[mid]["id"]) {
        return true;
    }
    if (key < info[mid]["id"]) {
        Lower = info.slice(0, mid);
        return Searching(key, Lower);
    }
    if (key > info[mid]["id"]) {
        upper = info.slice[mid + 1];
        return Searching(key, upper);
    }
}

function apply() {
    var key = input.value;
    if (Searching(key, info)) {
        p1.innerHTML = "id: " + info[key]["id"] + " title: " + info[key]["title"] + " price: " + info[key]["price"];
    } else {
        p1.innerHTML = "not found";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Search bar</p>
    <p><input id="input" placeholder="enter "><button type="button" onclick="apply()">search</button></p>
    <p1 id="p1"></p1>  
    <script src="source.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML so we can see your error in context.

Comment: What exactly is the error message, including the location in your script that it references?

Comment: I have upvoted for giving an easily runnable example of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your last if statement of `Searching` your are not using paranthesis to call the slice method:

```
if (key > info[mid]["id"]) {
        upper = info.slice[mid + 1];
        return Searching(key, upper);
```

Change it to:

```
if (key > info[mid]["id"]) {
        upper = info.slice(mid + 1);
        return Searching(key, upper);
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!!This just fixed my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your last if statement, in Searching method, has a recursion call in which the method name "Searching" is with lowercase "s". Change it from:

```
if (key > info[mid]["id"]) {
    upper = info.slice(mid + 1);
    return searching(key, upper);
}
```

To:

```
if (key > info[mid]["id"]) {
    upper = info.slice(mid + 1);
    return Searching(key, upper);
}
```

I also suggest that your change the code below from:

```
var key = input.value;
```

To:

```
var key = document.getElementById("input").value;
```

as your code may include further input tags afterwards. When you get by id you retrieve the element from what should be its unique id.